# How can I get the Samsung settings menu on a non Samsung Phone (Android)

Tags: samsung, settings

Just got a new phone for work, the trouble is that I am finding it really difficult to use and navigate the Android 6.0 settings menu on it as I am used to the one from Samsung. Is there any way I get the Samsung version of the settings menu on my new work phone? (Blu R1 HD)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not possible, or at the very least rather difficult. TouchWiz, which is Samsung's custom Android UI "skin", is not available to download and install on the device of your choosing.

There *might* be a way to get it running on a rooted phone but I'm guessing that's not something you want to attempt, especially if it's a work phone.

The only other possibility is to look into 3rd party launchers such as Nova but I don't know which, if any, affect the settings drawer.